# auto move to cart function

Tags: python, django

We are trying to figure how to move the auction item to the cart. We have our program removing the auction from the auction listing page, however we haven't gotten it to to move to the highest bidders cart.
Here is our auction_details function, mycart function
auctions_details

```
def auction_details(request, auction_id):
    auction = get_object_or_404(Auction, id=auction_id)
 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bid_form = BidForm(request.POST)
 
        if bid_form.is_valid():
            bid_amount = bid_form.cleaned_data['bid_amount']
 
            if bid_amount > auction.current_bid:
                # Update the auction details
                auction.current_bid = bid_amount
                auction.highest_bidder = request.user
                Bid.objects.create(bidder=request.user, auction=auction, amount=bid_amount)
                messages.success(request, f'Your bid successfully is placed at {timezone.now()}!')
                messages.success(request, f'The auction will expire at {auction.end_date}!')
                messages.success(request, f'Expired?  {auction.end_date <= timezone.now()}!')
            
                if auction.end_date <= timezone.now():
                    auction.ended = True
                
                    cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(user=auction.highest_bidder, auction=auction)
                    cart_item.quantity = 1
                    cart_item.save()

                auction.save()        
                
                return redirect('auction_details', auction_id=auction.id)
 
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Bid must be higher than the current bid.')

    else:
        bid_form = BidForm()

 
    return render(request, 'auctions/auction_details.html', {'auction': auction, 'bid_form': bid_form})

mycart fuction - 
def mycart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    else:
        cart_items = []

    total_amount = 0  # Initialize total amount to zero

    for item in cart_items:
        total_amount += item.auction.current_bid * item.quantity

    context = {
        'cart_items': cart_items,
        'total_amount': total_amount,  # Pass the total_amount to the template
    }

    return render(request, 'auctions/mycart.html', context)
```

We think there is something wrong with our line of code here:

```
if auction.end_date <= timezone.now():
                    auction.ended = True
```

And in the backend, when the auction ends it doesnt mark it as ended
If you require anything else let me know

We have tried playing around with

```
if auction.end_date <= timezone.now():
                    auction.ended = True
```

removing it, changing it up but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reorganize you if-else statements into [guard clauses](https://sourcery.ai/blog/explaining-refactorings-3/) to better identify the logic behind it:

```py
def auction_details(request, auction_id):
    auction = get_object_or_404(Auction, id=auction_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        return render(request, 'auctions/auction_details.html', {'auction': auction, 'bid_form': BidForm()})

    if not (bid_form := BidForm(request.POST)).is_valid():
        messages.error(request, 'Bid must be higher than the current bid.')
        return render(request, 'auctions/auction_details.html', {'auction': auction, 'bid_form': bid_form})

    if (bid_amount := bid_form.cleaned_data['bid_amount']) <= auction.current_bid:
        return render(request, 'auctions/auction_details.html', {'auction': auction, 'bid_form': bid_form})
    
    # Update the auction details
    auction.current_bid = bid_amount
    auction.highest_bidder = request.user
    Bid.objects.create(bidder=request.user, auction=auction, amount=bid_amount)
    messages.success(request, f'Your bid successfully is placed at {timezone.now()}!')
    messages.success(request, f'The auction will expire at {auction.end_date}!')
    messages.success(request, f'Expired?  {auction.end_date <= timezone.now()}!')

    if auction.end_date <= timezone.now():
        auction.ended = True

        cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
            user=auction.highest_bidder, auction=auction)
        cart_item.quantity = 1
        cart_item.save()

    auction.save()

    return redirect('auction_details', auction_id=auction.id)
```

By the looks of this, the `if auction.end_date <= timezone.now():` section will only be executed if a valid bid is made *after* the auction has expired.

A naive way to solve this issue is to place the part at the very beginning of the function:

```py
def auction_details(request, auction_id):
    auction = get_object_or_404(Auction, id=auction_id)

    if auction.end_date <= timezone.now():
        auction.ended = True

        cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
            user=auction.highest_bidder, auction=auction)
        cart_item.quantity = 1
        cart_item.save()
        auction.save()
        render(request, 'auctions/auction_details.html', {'auction': auction, 'bid_form': BidForm()})

    # [...] rest of code
```